# Since this is the first time this happened or Since this is the first time it happened

Tags: grammatical-number

Not sure what to use between **it** or **this** in the following sentence:

> Since this is the first time this happened, I'll just be converting the data top-up before to your usual 1GB Data plan as a one-off.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking with someone directly about an event that has just happened and what you will do about it, it would be better to refer to the event directly using "this." That makes it clear that you are talking about the situation at hand. I would also personally add "has" so it would read as follows:

> You went over your usage. Since this is the first time this has happened, I'll just be...

You would use the word "it" in a more indirect context, like if you were telling a story about something that happened repeatedly in the past

> You went over your usage many times this year. The first time it happened, I converted...